# Count rows in a data frame by factors, preserve order?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

I have the task to make a function which takes a path to a directory, reads a lot of .csv files and returns a data.frame with the number of complete cases for each file in the form:

```
##   id nobs
## 1  2 1041
## 2  4  474
## 3  8  192
## 4 10  148
## 5 12   96
```

I have the following solution (function signature is given):

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
  myFiles <- list.files(path=directory,pattern=".csv",recursive=T,full.names=T)
  data <- lapply(myFiles[id],read.csv)
  frame <- do.call("rbind",data)
  frame <- frame[complete.cases(frame),]
  frame$ID <- factor(frame$ID, ordered=T)
  by <- by(frame,frame$ID,nrow,simplify=F)
  complete <- data.frame(id=names(by),nobs=unlist(by))

  return(complete)
}
```

That gives me the correct output, except one situtation. If the function call is something like `complete(directory, 30:25)` it's expected, that the order of the data.frame column `id` is preserved (here 30,29, etc.). But that fails because `by` is sorting the output list by factors. Is there a better solution for my problem (using standard packages)? Or can I inhibit the ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `ordered=` parameter is doing what you think it is. When you set `ordered=T` it creates an ordered factor which is analogous to an ordinal variable where as a regular factor behaves more like a categorical variable. It does not assume the vector is already ordered nor does it affect the sorting of the vector in any way.

If you want to specify a given order, you must use

```
frame$ID <- factor(frame$ID, levels=unique(frame$ID))
```

and then `by` should behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I had a wrong idea about the function of the `odered` parameter. When I use `frame$ID <- factor(frame$ID,levels=unique(frame$ID))`I bring it to work correctly, but there is now another problem. With an input like `c(2, 4, 8, 10, 12)` the generated data.frame has the id-values in it's row.names field. Instead of 1,2,3,4,5 there is now 2,4,8,10,12 (I have to fullfill a unit test). The other parts (id, nobs) are correct now.

Comment: @Meiner Well, you are setting the IDs with `data.frame(id=names(by),nobs=unlist(by))` so instead of using `names(by)` just do `id=1:length(by)` or something like that.

Comment: The `id` field correct. I mean the numbers in the most left column when you print a data.frame (without a column name). I have to set `row.names=NULL`, then it works as expected. Before the change I did not have to do something like this.